# In Pathfinder bloody skeletons are permanently destroyed in an area of a Bless?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, undead

The [skeleton](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/skeleton.html) variant bloody skeleton has the special quality Deathless:

> Deathless (Su): A bloody skeleton is destroyed when reduced to 0 hit
>   points, but it returns to unlife 1 hour later at 1 hit point, allowing
>   its fast healing thereafter to resume healing it. A bloody skeleton
>   can be permanently destroyed if it is destroyed by positive energy, if
>   it is reduced to 0 hit points in the area of a bless or hallow spell,
>   or if its remains are sprinkled with a vial of holy water.

The point here is the destruction, if it is reduced to 0 HP in the area of a [Bless](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/bless.html) spell. That does not seem to make sense. Bless is a burst and every ally is affected that is in the burst, but not one that enters the area later (at least I think that works that way). Why should it have any effect on Bloody skeletons? [Hallow](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/hallow.html) makes sense, it affects an area. [Consecrate](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/consecrate.html) would make more sense than bless in that case. Is that an error, or what is the idea behind this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to be a case of the creature description being based on a development version of a spell that was changed before publication, but the bloody skeleton's ability wasn't updated to match. Or the design notes for the bloody skeleton read something like "or 0 hp on blessed ground" and the developer that actually wrote the text didn't do due diligence in translating that into the correct spells. However it happened, it's an error rather than a mysterious rules interaction.

Go with your gut, and change it to "the area of a consecrate or hallow spell". Pathfinder and d20 system games in general expect GMs to make their worlds believable rather than to slavishly follow rules into weird contradictions and twisted corner cases that break suspension of disbelief, so you're entirely in the right to change this in your own games. If you're a player in another GM's game, suggest the fix as a sensible thing to do, but leave it up to your GM.